# Jupyter Notebook cell stopped working as such

Tags: jupyter-notebook, cell

There is the first cell that is supposed to execute code as the rest, but somehow it's not even working at all.

The next cells are working properly, but this forst one doesn't recognize my input.

In the pictures provided you can see that the next cell recognizes my input as code and highlights the proper words in color. When I first opened the notebook it was alright, but it just stopped working for this first cell.

I have tried to close and reopen, interrupt kernel and everything in my hands.

Thank you very much for your time.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cell was not stuck on an infinite loop. Somehow Jupyter Notebook stopped recognizing it as a code cell. Therefore you have to manually srt it back to code cell. See image.[image]